# Number count does not work

Tags: jquery, scroll, nan

I want to increment counter like :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var nr = 1;
    $(window).scroll(function (nr) {
        alert(nr);
        nr++;
    });
});
```

I tried above which is not working!
Why `nr` returns `NaN` and why not `1` ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/FfStL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `nr` outside the scroll event handler function is a different variable from the one inside the event handler.

You have added `nr` as a parameter to the event handler. That's means that it is a local variable inside the function, and it shadows the variable `nr` from the outer scope.

If you remove the parameter, the variable inside the event handler is the same as the one outside:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var nr = 1;
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            alert(nr);
            nr++;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var nr = 1;
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            alert(nr);
            nr++;
        });
    });
```